# Connecting to MYSQL Server from SQL Yog

Tags: mysql, localhost, sqlyog

I know this question has been asked many times, but I couldn't solve my problem after seeing all the relevant questions.

I had installed Visual Studio 2012 Express edition on my Windows 7 Dell Inspiron laptop. So, Microsoft SQL Server was automatically installed along with it.

After that, I installed SQL Yog Community Edition. After starting it for the first time, I tried to connect to the MYSQL Host. I kept the information as it is, namely,

```
MySQL Host Address: localhost
Username: root
Port: 3306
```

I did not put any password.
After doing all this, when I said Connect, it gives the following error:

```
"Error No. 2003 Can't connect to MySQL Server on 'localhost' (10061)"
```

After all this, I thought the problem was with the installation of SQL on my machine. Hence I downloaded Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express Edition and installed it. But still, SQL Yog is facing the same problem.

What should I do?

Comment: This FAQ should help: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should check that MySQL server is started.
- Check the default port, is it 3306?
- The port may be forbidden, check the firewall if it is started.

Try to test address - localhost:3306 with [TELNET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) program -

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

Comment: Try [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition);-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but can you once try to connect using ** mysql query browser** http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html  instead of using sqlyog initially i have also faced the same problem with sqlyog but later i able to connect using mysql query browser

Comment: I downloaded MySQL Workbench instead of the query browser. But still it is unable to connect... Don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked:

> 1. Installed Connector .net
> 2. Installed Sql for Visual Studio
> 3. In database (MySql on Ubuntu) you must change host in users - % - then u can remote access to ur database.
> 4. hash bind address in cfg in /etc/my.conf

My version is Ultimate, but I want it on express version.